# Accessing values entered via form - try again

Tags: php, forms

I have entered a form element into the page contents editor in wordpress.

form action="/home4/stevekeo/public_html/wp-includes/testforms.php" method="post"> ...

I want to use the selected value, and have created a php script in the /home4/stevekeo/public_html/wp-includes folder to access the user choice.

```
<?php
  $team = $_POST['teamname'];
  echo "Team selected was ". $team. ".<br />";
 ?>
```

As I understand it, the PHP script named in the 'action' part of the form element is executed when the submit button is clicked. This doesn't appear to happen. Any help would be great, as I'm a relative WP/PHP novice.
sorry - first attempt was mangled

Answer (score 0):

You are right the action part is the directory to the execution script file.
You can not use the static directory path like that, it should be used with get_home_path(); like

```
$path = get_home_path();
then action = '<?php echo $path."wp-includes/tests-form.php" ?>';
```

More: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path

Answer (score 0):

Rather that entering form element into the page contents editor in wordpress, make a separate template and load it through "Page Attribute".

Then in form action, place below:

```
action="<?php echo home_url('/page-name'); ?>"
```

Let me know if any problems.